# can't specify image path inside js file

Tags: html, image, path

I am trying to import image from 'images' folder inside 'home.js' file which is inside components folder. I tried many combinations of '../' and './', but image doesn't load on page. There is probably something wrong with a path.

[image: my directory looks like this]

[image: tree screenshoot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct syntax in react is:

`import astronaut from '../images/astronaut.png';`

`<img src={astronaut} alt="logo" />`

Comment: what was the command which was generating a directory tree?

Comment: tree /f > tree.txt

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using React, did you check if the component is even being rendered to the view at all?
Additional factor could be your applied classes '`home-wrapper`' or '`backImg`'

I usually add some placeholder text to check if it pops up.

Regarding to Omars answer, that's right you would only need to go back two directories to access that image, like so

```
<img src="../../images/astronaut.png" alt="astronaut"/>
```

Comment: yes I added a placeholder and it's rendered. My path looks exactly like you have written but image doesn't load anyway.

Comment: Alright, did you try out one of the other provided solutions like Quentins hint to importig the image ?

Comment: yes I solved this problem. quentin's approach is right, but import path should fall within src folder so I just moved that folder inside.

Comment: Great to hear, yes the file should sit in the src folder to be processed by Webpack. I just learned that too.

Answer (score 1):

When you provide a relative URL, it has to go from the URL of the HTML to the URL of the image.

You are trying to go from the file path of the JavaScript file to the file path of the image.

Since the image is not in the *public* directory, it is quite likely that the image doesn't even have a URL in the first place.

---

There are two basic approaches you can use to determine the URL here.

### Manually

You need to put the image somewhere it has a URL.

How you do this will depend on the HTTP server you are using. You will need to ensure that the image has the same URL (or at least one relative to the HTML document) in both your development and production environments.

For example, you could put it in the *public* directory, then say `src="public/images/yourimage.jpeg"`. (Note that I'm making assumptions about how your development server allocates URLs to files in the public directory here).

### Use your bundler

Typically when using React (as you appear to be doing) you will use a tool like Webpack to generate a production ready version of the site. This will do things like removing slow debugging routines, tree shaking to remove code from modules that isn't being used, and so on.

Webpack has [features for handling images](https://webpack.js.org/guides/asset-management/#loading-images) so once you set up the configuration file to support it, you can then do:

```
import MyImage from '../../../images/yourimage.jpeg';
```

and

```
<img src={MyImage} alt="etc etc" />
```

Note that the path here **is** relative to the JS file and that you need to use `{}` to assign a variable's value to `src`.

Comment: when using react this approach works `import MyImage from '../../../images/yourimage.jpeg';`  `<img src={MyImage} alt="etc etc" />` but import must fall within src folder. In my case  images folder was outside src folder so I just moved it inside.